# How to make exception to my Route in laravel, for my spa app?

Tags: laravel, routes

I've developed an app for my homework and It's base on `Vue.js, Laravel`, base on tutorials, my problem is base on tutorial I've learned, I've wrote this app and now i can't access any route except my app.

I want to create a about page, and when i add route to route it's going to my default page of spa app, which, I've did it base on tutorials to prevent people to type nonsense in URL like `url.com/asdasdqwe`, so how to add exception to the line that's preventing me to access other routes?

Here's the code:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('dashboard');

// I know this line make my app to force it to don't access other routes like bottom('/about')
// Route::get('{path}',"HomeController@index")->where( 'path', '([A-z\d-\/_.]+)?' );


// Because of top code i can't access other views that's using ('/etcroute')
Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

So when i remove `{path}` line i'll get some problem in SPA app. so I'm looking for a way to add exception or force it let these routes work with `{Path}` line.

Comment: Have you tried putting /about route code above /{path} route code?

Comment: @TarekAdam nah, i didn't know about priority of lines in routes. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow :)

To resolve this, simply place your '/about' route **above** the one with the regex match.

Laravel processes routes in order that they are listed, so your '/about' route is not being seen because the other one is matching it first.

For example:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('dashboard');

Route::get('{path}', 'HomeController@index')->where('path', '([A-z\d-\/_.]+)?');
```

Answer (score 0):

Route::get('dashboard/{any}', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->where(['any' => '.*']);

Answer (score 0):

Change your routings sort like this:

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('dashboard');

// Because of top code i can't access other views that's using ('/etcroute')
Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('{path}',"HomeController@index")->where( 'path', '([A-z\d-\/_.]+)?' );
```

Laravel routing begins from the top of web.php files and checks the routings one by one.

So you have to add regex at the end of your static routes.